# d3.js tooltip doesnt show

Tags: d3.js, tooltip

I am trying to add tooltip, it doesnt show for some reason. Please help. Here's the code https://codepen.io/gladiator_kris/pen/pojgEyQ?editors=0010

```
 var tooltip = svg.append("div")
                      .attr("id", "tooltip")
                      .style("opacity", 0.8);
```

```
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      tooltip.style("display", "flex")
             .html(function() {return 'tooltip'})
             .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10)+"px")
             .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px")
    })
    .on("mouseout", () => {
      tooltip.style("display", "none")
});
```

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by the fact that the tooltip is an HTML `div`, and is being appended to the SVG. `div` is not a valid SVG tag, so it is not displayed.

This can be fixed by appending the div to `div#graph`, as shown below:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("#Graph").append("div")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I appended it to the body element & it worked & was wondering why isn't it working on the svg. That really helps.:)